# How to make the text search string longer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to make the text search string longer? So that it will be remembered in the settings and always be there when the editor starts?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ssia.jpg)

Comment: if you can't find a setting that controls this add a feature request to the VSC repo, and maybe also a font spec, typing regex with variable with font is hard

Comment: 1) what does its length have to do with whether the value is persisted between editor restarts? 2) settings like this tend to have "preserveInput" in their names. Ex. `workbench.commandPalette.preserveInput`, `workbench.quickOpen.preserveInput`. I don't see such a setting for the find widget. I suggest like rioV8 to open a feature-request issue ticket (Ex. `editor.findWidget.preserveInput`). If you do, please add a link here to it for posterity. But even then, those input preserving settings tend to just be preserved within one "session" and are forgotten when the application is closed.